# Add lines over the Outline Threejs

Tags: three.js

I've added an OutlinePass to my mesh, but I have also some lines that has to be over that outlinepass, is that possible to do?

```
// Crea una instancia de EffectComposer
    this.compose = new EffectComposer(this.renderer);

    // Agrega el render pass a la instancia de EffectComposer
    var renderPass = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.compose.addPass(renderPass);

    // Crea una instancia de OutlinePass y agrega la malla del cubo a los objetos seleccionados
    var outlinePass = new OutlinePass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), this.scene, this.camera);
    outlinePass.renderToScreen = true;
    outlinePass.selectedObjects.push(this.mesh);
    

    
    // -- parameter config
    outlinePass.edgeStrength = 60;
    outlinePass.edgeGlow = 0;
    outlinePass.edgeThickness = 5;
    outlinePass.pulsePeriod = 0;
    outlinePass.usePatternTexture = false; // patter texture for an object mesh
    outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor.set("#CCCCCC"); // set basic edge color
    outlinePass.hiddenEdgeColor.set("#CCCCCC"); // set edge color when it hidden by other objects
    outlinePass.overlayMaterial.blending = THREE.CustomBlending

    this.compose.addPass(outlinePass);

   


    // Agrega un efecto FXAA para suavizar los bordes del contorno
    var effectFXAA = new ShaderPass(FXAAShader);
    effectFXAA.uniforms["resolution"].value.set(
        1 / window.innerWidth,
        1 / window.innerHeight
    );
    effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true;
    this.compose.addPass(effectFXAA);
    this.createWideLine(new Vector3(0,0,56),new Vector3(-300,0,56), new THREE.Color(0x00FF00));
```

That's the actual result:
[image: outline]

As you can see the lines are under the outlinepass and I need to have that lines over the outlinepass.

Really thanks

Answer (score 1):

Outline Pass is rendered in a separate pass after the scene is rendered so it will be always on top
if you want to draw lines on top of the outline create a different scene similar to SceneHelper in Three.js Editor and render it using another render pass after outline pass

```
 var renderPassScene = new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera);
 this.compose.addPass(renderPassScene);
 var outlinePass = new OutlinePass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), this.scene, this.camera);
 // ....
 var renderPassSceneHelper = new RenderPass(this.sceneHelper, this.camera);
 this.compose.addPass(renderPassSceneHelper );
```

Add The lines you need on top to sceneHelper instead of Scene

[reference for render function in three.js editor](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/Viewport.js#L742)

Comment: Hello Mohammed, That's not the way to fix that, but you just give me the idea to do that in another scene. If I add another pass to the compose it ignores the first scene and only renders the second one. 

But I solved that by just rendering after the compose on the render() function like this:

```this.renderer.clear();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        
        if (this.compose) {
            this.compose.render()
            this.renderer.render(this.sceneHelper, this.camera);
        }```